# How to clean up a bad OpenSSL connection

Tags: c++, c, openssl

If a call to SSL_accept fails, I want to just bail out.

Currently I'm calling SSL_shutdown and then SSL_free, but since implementing this, two customers have had crashes deep down in OpenSSL (when calling SSL_accept at a later time), so I'm guessing maybe this isn't the best way to clean up.

The docs say SSL_shutdown is used to correctly cleanup, and it might need to be called twice (although if SSL_accept failed, I wouldn't think that would be the case).  SSL_clear is another option, but it seems like more of a connection reset.

SSL_free decrements a reference count and deletes the connection if the reference count hits 0.  I know my code doesn't have any references, but the 'session' might?

Is there a definitive way for completely closing/shutting down/freeing an SSL object with OpenSSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've called `SSL_free()` on the `SSL` object, you shouldn't use it again.  You need to ensure that a new SSL is created with `SSL_new()` for the subsequent `SSL_accept()`.

Comment: I'm definitely not reusing the SSL* after calling SSL_free.

So once I call SSL_free(), that's all I have to do to clean it up?  No matter what errors or connections happened previously?

Comment: @DougN: Correct.  Note that `SSL_free()` also frees the underlying BIOs - could that be the source of your problem?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that the BIOs are _not_ freed. As far as I know, it's just SSL_shutdown and then SSL_free. Then nothing is touched again. Guess I'm doing it right (but will double check the BIOs) -- hopefully the crashes are just coincedence... Thanks for the help.

Comment: When I call `SSL_free()`, I notice that the `BIO`s associated with the `SSL` are freed/gibberish. Then I set `bio = NULL;`